# Firestore authentication for multiple devices

Tags: c++, rest, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm developing linux c++ desktop application that connects to Firebase. The app will be deployed on multiple devices. Is it possible to perform REST authentication (Sign in with email / password) for all of these devices using one common e-mail address or will it trigger a security alert when more than one sign in operations are performed at the same time? Is there any better solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user can sign in to Firebase Authentication from multiple devices. There is no inherent limit to the number of devices a single user can sign in from.